# Ошибка после установки VirtualBox в usbport.sys

Tags: windows, debian, virtualbox

У меня debian 6. Установил себе virtualbox4.1.8... После установки устройств в windows XP выбивает ошибку usbport.sys (причем на разных образах и дисках). Я решил, что это проблема в virtualbox. Подскажите, что это может быть. ((

спасибо...я обновил и все заработало

Comment: Что то такое припоминаю в новой версии,а у меня не запускались образы.Выдавало "fatal_error" установил предыдущую версию virtualbox и все заработало.

Comment: обновил...все заработало...спасибо всем

Answer (score 1):

как вариант отключите USB в настройках вирт.машины. Посмотрите если загрузится, значит не корректно отрабатывает. Драйвера гостевой системы установлены?

Comment: драйвера не установлены(вроде) а когда отключаю юсб в настройках - у меня ни мышь, ни клава не работают(

Comment: установите драйвера гостевой системы. попробуйте virtualbox предыдущей версии, может конфликт какой, хотя с таким не сталкивался.